# Is the server running on host "localhost" Django and PostgreSQL Connection?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to run migrate command in Django on MAC.

> python3 manage.py migrate

But, I stuck in an error. The error says :

> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I am using PgAdmin4 and it is running on the web. I downloaded the postgresql and pgadmin4 and installed it.

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dj_learning',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is running on the web"? Is your postgresql server installed locally? if so how did you start it? Normally you'd do something like `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`

Comment: as @dirkgroten mentioned, it sounds like you need to start postgres.